# PowerShell - call variable with extension

Tags: powershell

How can I make this work with extension tacked on the end of my variable?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryPath*.pdf -Recurse -Force |
```

After fixing with below answer I now have:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $($directoryPath)*.pdf -Recurse -Force | 
ForEach-Object {
    $newname = "${input}_{0}.pdf" -f $i 
    $i++
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having with it? Works fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$($directoryPath)*.pdf" -Recurse -Force |
```

Should do.

If you need to concat a variable name with a string, or need to put an expression in your string, use `$(expression)` syntax.

Comment: Not strictly necessary if the object is just a string. This must be used when accessing object properties but any normal string variable should interpolate by default. However, don't disagree with this in practice for readability reasons

Comment: @arco444 In fact, if an object implements `toString()` properly, `$($variable)` will return an expected value. If not, the programmer will have to specify a property or a method to return a needed string. The closest example for me is `PSCredential`, if stuffed like this it results in a class name, instead you can write `$($cred.username)` to get accessible data from it.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that in your answer `"$($directoryPath)*.pdf"` is identical to `"$directoryPath*.pdf"` i.e. the parenthesis are not required here

Comment: Worked like a charm.  My full code is this:  Get-ChildItem -Path $($directoryPath)*.pdf -Recurse -Force | 
ForEach-Object {
    $newname = "${input}_{0}.pdf" -f $i 
    $i++
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname
}.  Before I made the above change, it didn't find any matching files and therefore didn't work at all/failed.